# How to migrate resources from proprietary CMS?

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler

I need to migrate our website from a proprietary CMS that uses active server pages.  Is there a tool or technique that will help download the resources from the existing site?  I guess I'm looking for a tool that will crawl and scrape the entire site.

An additional challenge is that the site uses SSL and is protected with forms-based authentication.  I have the necessary credentials and I can grab the cookie that validates the session but I'm not sure where to go from here and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if existing tools can help me.

EDIT - I'm using Windows OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wget may be a good tool for you to use

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --mirror --page-requisites http://example.com/
```

add --convert-links if you wish to make it more suitably for a local archive, rather than something you can re-upload somewhere.

A windows version of wget is available from the gnuwin32 project on sourceforge.net
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
wget --http-user:username --http-pass:password -r http://yoursite.com
```

This will fetch the entire site (recursively). If you're on windows, you'll want to install cygwin or something similar to use it, though I believe there are windows versions/clones of wget that you can download.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Perl, you might like [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.54/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm). Depends on the level of automation you are trying to achieve – `wget` would probably do just fine for some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options.  One thing to consider is how complex the authentication is.  Besides [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), you can look at [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) (a very robust option with bindings for many different languages), Python's [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html), [WWW-Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/), etc.